# How to Load Content into an ASP.NET MVC Partial View in a Layout View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

'm using ASP.NET MVC 3 with Razor views. I have a partial view which I would like to render on all pages so I am placing it in the site's main Layout page. However, I am not sure the best way to load data into the partial view. I could load it for each ActionMethod but there is there a way to do this globally across the entire app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move all the data loading logic for your partial into a separate action method.

Then in your layout page, instead of rendering the partial with a call to RenderPartial(), call the RenderAction() method.

RenderAction() makes a "child" action call - thus putting all the logic needed for that partial into one place.

Answer (score 2):

Write action for this partial view in MasterController because every controller inherits from it, and place your partial view in shared folder and call it on Site's master page (like every site has a user control which gives login box until user is logged in else it displays logged in user info) ... hope it answer your ques ...

Comment: Isn't this for MVC 2 using the old master page / usercontrols ? As I stated I am using Razor.

Comment: sorry misunderstood ... not worked on MVC3 but i was reading a post about MVC3, chk it here http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/22/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts.aspx and do check the _ViewStart file part ... i think thts you are looking for ...